Recommended dynamical systems book
I'm searching for strong books on dynamical systems and discrete dynamical system. My level is a master's degree on Mathematics but i want to study in depth the theory of ODE and dynamical systems.

Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos by Strogatz is one book to be aware of. Also Hirsch and Smale is worth a look.

And what do you think about differential equations and dynamical systems by Perko?

I don’t know that one but it could be good.
